# Probability Bayes Theorem

Tags: probability, bayesian, bayes-theorem

I'm new to probability. I'm trying to learn bayes theorem.

I came across this question.

> ** Two machines M & N are used to produce chocolates. M produces 60% of total chocolates and N produces 40%. Given 70% of chocolates by M and 80% of chocolates by N are normal and the rest are faulty. Now, I'm confused about applying bayes theorem for the following question: 
>   * A chocolate is chosen and found out to be normal. What is the probability of it being from machine M* **

My approach is P(A) = 0.6

p(B) = 0.4

Now I'm confused on what is the condition to be applied and what is p(A|B)? Is it applicable or not. Any suggestion would be great.

Comment: $p($faulty$|M)=0.3$ and $p($faulty$|N)=0.2$

Comment: Hey @GregoryGrant, what do you think of the formula I wrote down. Is it correct?

Answer (score 1):

Denote $P(normal|M) = 0.7$ and $P(normal|N) = 0.8$.

Computing the $P(M|normal)$ is our target.

By bayes theorem

$$
P(M|normal) = \frac{P(normal|M)P(M)}{P(noraml)} = \frac{P(normal|M)P(M)}{P(normal|M)+P(normal|N)}$$

Comment: Hey @vincen, I think it should be **(P(normal|M)P(M))/(P(M)*P(normal|M)+P(N)*P(normal|N))** isn't it correct?

Comment: Sorry,You are right!I take some foolish mistake.